# How to make custom list with three columns with text in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, custom-lists

This is my code,in this code i put data in the string array and through looping i put all the data into the list called AcerList and give that list to adapter. The by getting the index from previous class i am checking the condition according to which i am giving an adapter if it's legal.

```
ListView lstView;
String AcerProductsArray[] = { "Acer Aspire V5-571 Ultra Book i3","AceAspireS3391i3","Acer Aspire S3-391 i3"};
ArrayList<String> AcerList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String>  AcerAdapter;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.selectedcategory);

        lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        try{
            for(int i=0;i<AcerProductsArray.length;i++)
            {
                AcerList.add(AcerProductsArray[i]);
            }catch(){}

AcerAdapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, AcerList);
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        int index = 0;
        index = extras.getInt("index");
        if(index == 0){
            lstView.setAdapter(AcerAdapter);
                   AcerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

This is my output.But i also want to set the price and details using customized lists,In xml file i have only one list and three textViews. i havent use any database all the programe in hard coded.Please help me in solving this..

[image]

Comment: use a custom listview

Comment: sir i google alot but couldn't able to understand the code..a simple example would be very helpful..

Answer (score 0):

A string array is not going to work for you. Define a class e.g Acer and define all the required attributes for the class. Then pass an array of the Acer objects to your adapter rather then Strings. e.g

The Acer class:

```
    public class Acer{
        String name;
        String price;
        String details;

        public Acer(String _name, String _price, String _details){
            this.name =_name;
            this.price = _price;
            this.details = _details;
        }
    }
```

Then pass an array of Acer objects to your adapter and you will be able to acess all the properties for an object inside the adapter. e.g if you want the price for the selected item, you would do this inside the adapter :

```
    array_of_acers.get(position).price;
```

Also you would be needing a custom array adapter for this. A nice and simple example for a custom listview with custom adapter is given [here](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429)

Comment: I opened it again a sec ago. its working fine. bw you could find other good tutorials too on creating a custom adapter with user defined objects for a list view